# Get List of Items in SharePoint List

Tags: development, list, web

I am trying to get a list of items that are contained inside a sharepoint list. When I use the code below I get an error

> [ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.GetListByName(String
>   strListName, Boolean bThrowException)
>   ...

The structure is MainSite>Subweb>Subweb>Subweb>List

Am I calling this wrong since it is inside of 3 subwebs?

```
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url.ToString()))
                    using (SPWeb oWebsiteRoot = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPList oList = oWebsiteRoot.Lists["SInfo"];
                        SPListItemCollection items = oList.Items;

                        foreach (SPListItem listitem in items)
                        {
                            Response.Write(SPEncode.HtmlEncode(listitem["SName"].ToString()) + "<BR>");
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url.ToString())` and then calling OpenWeb will open the Root Web of the Site Collection, instead of your subweb. Thus, when you try to get that List it can't find it, giving that error message.

Try `new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url)` instead, this opens up the SPSite pointing to your current subweb, and then the call to OpenWeb() will open up the subweb (because the url passed in points to the subweb).

Answer (score 0):

I think a simpler way of doing this would be just using the SPContext.Current.Web object instead of creating new SPWeb and SPSite objects.

```
                    SPListItemCollection items = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["SInfo"].Items;

                    foreach (SPListItem listitem in items)
                    {
                        Response.Write(SPEncode.HtmlEncode(listitem["SName"].ToString()) + "<BR>");
                    }
```

Comment: Agreed, unless this block is inside an SPElevatedPrivileges call.